# Symfony - Manage a big amount of data uploads to server

Tags: php, symfony, storage, data-management

I'm currently working on a management system for a 50 people agency. 
Those people needs to upload a **huge amount of data** to the server (thousands of files, light and heavy ones, can be **several gigabytes**)

I can upload file to the mail server, but **I want to manage those files on a storage server**.
How could I transfer my files to my storage server and give back storage informations to the web server ?
What would be the better solution to manage this kind of storage with a Symfony app ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could use S3 from AWS. From symfony you can manage it. Regards

Comment: Hi Albeis, thanks for your answer. The app is local based, and I can't use third party services as AWS :/ Employees must be able to manage files on our storage server directly.

And I forgot to mention that I can't transfer files via RSYNC or FTP every hour or so, because employees are working on the files simultaneously. So I must upload files directly on storage server

Comment: What about using something like Nextcloud for your File Handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) as a filesystem abstraction layer and implement your own [custom adapter](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/adapters/service.md) service to provide methods to communicate with your remote storage.

```
# app/config/config.yml
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        foo:
            service:
                id:     my.adapter.service
```

Comment: Seems like this is exactly what I need ! I didn't know about Gaufrette. I get into it right now !

Thanks Mikhail